# Confusion about Bootstrap 2 and jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

In my jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/5fs7e6wt/5/

I manually import jQuery 1.7.2 from a Google CDN but as you can see the dropdown does not work.

However, when I change jsfiddle to use jQuery 1.7.2 onLoad within the left side bar, the drop down now appears to work.

I am fairly confused as to what changed in my dev environment or what jsfiddle is pulling in additionally that I am missing?

Any advice on how to debug this situation would be very appreciated.

Just looking at the new "sources" pulled in from the page source is fairly counfusing as it is mixed with the pre-existing jsfiddle javascript.

My imports look like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see jQuery being imported in that fiddle. You're grabbing the Bootstrap CSS, the FontAwesome CSS, and the Bootstrap JavaScript. No jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I must have accidentally removed it at some point. However, I added it back in.

Comment: jQuery has to load first. Before Bootstrap.

Comment: @Andy - You'll want to load jQuery before Bootstrap (since Bootstrap depends on jQuery) - Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fs7e6wt/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are including bootstrap before jQuery. If you check out the console you will see that you are getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Simply switch the script elements like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fs7e6wt/8/).

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```